# Pass datetime to sql server stored procedure add 1 second

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I try to pass a DateTime in c# to SQL server stored procedure, however, 1 second is being added to one of the dates, which is the toDate. For the fromDate, the time is 
7/1/2017 12:00:00 AM, for the toDate, the time is 7/31/2017 11:59:59 PM. However, when it comes to SQL server profiler, I found the toDate is changed to 2017-08-01 00:00:00.

The following is my C# code, on which 7/31/2017 11:59:59 PM is passed to toDate

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectUsage4", conn))
                {
                    SqlParameter param = null;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
                    param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ConvertToParam("ids"), ids ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    param.DbType = DbType.String;
                    param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ConvertToParam("locationIDs"), locationIDs ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    param.DbType = DbType.String;
                    param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ConvertToParam("indicatorIDs"), indicatorIDs ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    param.DbType = DbType.String;
                    param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ConvertToParam("fromDate"), fromDate ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
                    param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ConvertToParam("toDate"), toDate ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

And here is the SQL Server Profiler, you can see the time is changed to 2018-08-01 00:00:00 passing to the @p_todate

```
exec SelectUsage4 @p_ids=NULL,@p_locationIDs=N'6,7,8',@p_indicatorIDs=N'94',@p_fromDate='2017-07-01 00:00:00',@p_toDate='2017-08-01 00:00:00',@p_yearly=NULL,@p_monthly=NULL,@p_halfYear1=NULL,@p_halfYear2=NULL,@p_fourMonths1=NULL,@p_fourMonths2=NULL,@p_fourMonths3=NULL,@p_q1=NULL,@p_q2=NULL,@p_q3=NULL,@p_q4=NULL,@p_biMonthly1=NULL,@p_biMonthly2=NULL,@p_biMonthly3=NULL,@p_biMonthly4=NULL,@p_biMonthly5=NULL,@p_biMonthly6=NULL,@p_approvalStatus=NULL,@p_LANGUAGE=N'en-US'
```

And here is the declaration of the stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectUsage4](

  @p_ids VARCHAR(max)
, @p_locationIDs VARCHAR(max)
, @p_indicatorIDs VARCHAR(max)
, @p_fromDate datetime
, @p_toDate datetime
, @p_yearly smallint
, @p_monthly smallint
, @p_halfYear1 smallint
, @p_halfYear2 smallint
, @p_fourMonths1 smallint
, @p_fourMonths2 smallint
, @p_fourMonths3 smallint
, @p_q1 smallint
, @p_q2 smallint
, @p_q3 smallint
, @p_q4 smallint
, @p_biMonthly1 smallint
, @p_biMonthly2 smallint
, @p_biMonthly3 smallint
, @p_biMonthly4 smallint
, @p_biMonthly5 smallint
, @p_biMonthly6 smallint
, @p_approvalStatus int
, @p_language nvarchar(10)
```

)

I am not quite understand why 1 second is being added to the toDate from C# to SQL server.

Comment: Is `toDate` (on the C# side) 23:59:59.000 or (more likely) 23:59:59.999? SQL Server's `datetime` cannot represent all millisecond values so .NET would round it up during conversion.

Comment: (It's almost always better to represent datetime intervals as (inclusive start, exclusive end) anyway, because that way you don't have to care about the precision)

Comment: is a @p_fromDate='2017-07-01 00:00:00' expected result for you?

Comment: Side note, [avoid AddWithValue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: A DateTime cannot be a null.  So I'm not sure what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Compare `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-07-31 23:59:59.997')`, `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-07-31 23:59:59.999')`. There's a reason `DATETIME2` was introduced. For this reason, among others, Damien's point about using exclusive upper bounds is especially pertinent to `DATETIME` -- inclusive upper bounds get really inconvenient.

Comment: @gabba Yes,the p_fromdate is the expected result.

Comment: @want_to_be_calm C# won't add 1 second. Neither will SQL Server. You didn't post the definition of `toDate` or any code that actually sets it to `23:59:59`. As jdweng explained you *can't* have a null DateTime (it's a struct) so `toDate` can't be a DateTime variable. `toDate ?? (object)DBNull.Value` would throw a compilation error if it were. The problem is most likely in the code you use to produce `toDate`

Comment: @want_to_be_calm if you want to compare *dates*, without the time component, you can cast a `datetime` field to `date` and still use any existing indexes. SQL Server is fast enough to convert `where cast(dateFiled as date)='20180911'` to a range query equivalent to `where datefield >='20180911' and datefield <'20180912'`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if it’s 23:59:59.999, can I format it to 23:59:59?